# ListView is not populating, yet getView() is called

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I've spent the last day attempting to populate my ListView object with the results of a Google Places request. The request is fine, there are definitely items coming into my data object. But when I attempt to add this data to the ListView, no matter what I try I always get empty rows. getView() is being called, but it seems to have no effect. Here are the relevant snippets of code:

My main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gps_activate_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:text="@string/gps_activate_button"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/results_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>

<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:text="No data" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My custom row to display Places information:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/custom_row_icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dip">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip" 
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/reference_text_view" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:textColor="#999999" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/rating_text_view" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:textColor="#EBE41C" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results_list_view);
    gpSearchResponse = new GooglePlacesSearchResponse();
    gpAdapter = new GooglePlacesSearchResponseAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_gp_result_row, gpSearchResponse.getGpSearchResults());
    lv.setAdapter(gpAdapter);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    viewGooglePlacesSearchResults = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location == null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            getGooglePlacesSearchResults(location);
        }
    };
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewGooglePlacesSearchResults, "GooglePlacesBackground");
    thread.start();
    searchResultsDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
}
```

getGooglePlacesSearchResults:

```
private void getGooglePlacesSearchResults(Location location) {
    try {
        GooglePlacesSearchResponseHandler handler = new GooglePlacesSearchResponseHandler();
        String FINAL_URL = PLACES_SEARCH_URL + "location=" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude() +"&radius=5000&types=bar%7Cmovie_theater%7Cnight_club%7Crestaurant%7Cshopping_mall&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyD-GWPYtYJMbJuTXuTVXfGXKlVPuWD0d6Q";
        JSONObject json = handler.getJSONFromUrl(FINAL_URL); // getting JSON
        Log.i("URL", FINAL_URL);
        GooglePlacesSearchResponseParser parser = new GooglePlacesSearchResponseParser();
        try {
            gpSearchResponse = parser.parseResults(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ gpSearchResponse.getGpSearchResults().size());
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
    }
    runOnUiThread(returnResults);
}
```

my Overridden getView() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_gp_result_row, null);
            }
            GooglePlacesSearchResult gpSearchResult = items.get(position);
            if (gpSearchResult != null) {
                    //ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
                    TextView referenceTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reference_text_view);
                    TextView ratingTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rating_text_view);
                    /*if (iconImageView != null) {
                          iconImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(Uri.encode(gpSearchResult.getIconURL())));
                    }*/
                    if(nameTextView != null){
                          nameTextView.setText(gpSearchResult.getName());
                    }
                    if (referenceTextView != null) {
                          referenceTextView.setText(gpSearchResult.getReference());                            
                    }
                    if(ratingTextView != null){
                          ratingTextView.setText(gpSearchResult.getRating());
                    }
            }
            return v;
    }
```

And a Runnable object that notifies the adapter:

```
private Runnable returnResults = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (gpSearchResponse.getGpSearchResults() != null && gpSearchResponse.getGpSearchResults().size() > 0) {
            gpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gpAdapter.setGooglePlacesSearchResult(gpSearchResponse.getGpSearchResults());
        }
        searchResultsDialog.dismiss();
        gpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

I'm very new to Android development so there are large gaps in my knowledge, but as best I can tell it seems that getView() is the source of the problem, since despite the fact that it gets called and does indeed get filled with my object, nothing happens on screen.

Finally, I based much of the threading and UI stuff off of this code here: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a friend look at the code with me, and the solution was sadly not nearly as interesting as I'd hoped it would be. It turns out there was simply a problem with my custom row xml, where I accidentally set the height to 0. I suppose if anything this is a reminder to take a break once in while...below is the updated XML for anyone who's interested.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/custom_row_icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dip">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30sp" 
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/vicinity_text_view" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:textColor="#999999" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/rating_text_view" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:textColor="#EBE41C" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```